# Python findall regex

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to use `re.findall(pattern, string)` to pull out a Jira Key from a Git Log line. My example input would be something like:

```
58df2ac Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/ABC-1234' into release-1.1.0
df40f59 Merge branch 'ABC-2345' into release-1.1.1
```

And what I want to get out of this is just the `ABC-1234` & `ABC-2345`.

I know the logic I'd want to use would be starts with `ABC-` and goes to until it finds a non number like a quote, space or letter.

Any help in figuring the correct regex would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
 re.findall('ABC-[0-9]+', string)
```

`[0-9]` specifies any Arabic numeral. It is preferable to `\d` because the latter's behavior depends on the active locale. The `+` specifies that the previous  pattern must be matched one or more times.

Comment: Thanks, that was close to what I figured out. I had `re.findall(r'ABC-\d+', string)` but specifying 0-9 would be better.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import re

st='''\
58df2ac Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/ABC-1234' into release-1.1.0
df40f59 Merge branch 'ABC-2345' into release-1.1.1'''

for line in st.splitlines():
    print re.findall(r"'.*ABC-(.*)'",line)
```

Or, if you know that 'ABC-XXX' is only digits, this is better:

```
    print re.findall(r"'.*ABC-(\d+)",line)
```

Either case, prints:

```
['1234']
['2345']
```